# Transclusion - These are not the Categories you are looking for

Tags: mediawiki, transclusion, mediawiki-templates, wikia

I have a template on Wikia
http://shadow-of-war-mobile.wikia.com/wiki/Template:Orc

This template eventually will nothing but a middle-man template through a chain of inheritence.

But I digress, I need to figure out how to have the original article that uses the template (for instance: http://shadow-of-war-mobile.wikia.com/wiki/Narz_the_Murderous) to have the appropriate categories, which it does.

What i need to is to put a stop-gap to Category Scope creep.  By this I am referring to Pages that may Transclude the source page do not need to also inherit the Categories that originated from the Templates use.

## Source Template (http://shadow-of-war-mobile.wikia.com/wiki/Template:Orc):

```
<onlyinclude><div style="float:right; background-color:dimgray; width:200px">
{| 
!  {{{name}}}
|-
| [[File:{{{name}}}.jpg|upright|{{{name}}}]]
|-
{|
| Rank: || {{cat|{{{rank}}}|{{{name}}}}}
|-
| Class: || {{cat|{{{class}}}|{{{name}}}}}
|-
| Tribe: || {{cat|{{{tribe}}}|{{{name}}}}}
|}
|}
</div></onlyinclude>{{documentation}}[[Category:Character Templates]]
```

## Article Usage (http://shadow-of-war-mobile.wikia.com/wiki/Narz_the_Murderous):

```
{{Orc|name=Narz the Murderous|rank=Overlord|class=Marksman|tribe=Feral}}
```

## Problem Article: http://shadow-of-war-mobile.wikia.com/wiki/Warlords:Talion%27s_Revenge

As you will see the same categories that are in the source article are also in the problem article.

## Question

I remember a decade ago, or so, there was an approach to allow for the source article to utilize the categories, while preventing any other articles from inheriting, through transclusion, the categories of the source article.  I just can't remember the approach that was taken or used to pull this off.

I have tried using Google to find the possible answer but have come up short of the solution, so far.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing. The related feature request is [T2835](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T2835) (I wouldn't hold my breath). Your best bet is to make categories optional in your source template ([example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Category_suppression#Attribute-based_suppression_examples)).

Comment: It is possible, it is using HTML trickery.  Effectively, Late Binding but can't remember the methodology to use for the effect.  It uses non-direct syntax, sorta like `{{!}}` does for tables